# Why is hypophosphorous acid (H3PO2) a strong reducing agent?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

Why is [hypophosphorous acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypophosphorous_acid) $(\ce{H3PO2})$ a strong reducing agent? the oxidation state of phosphorous in $\ce{H3PO2}$ is $+5$, as hydrogen and oxygen both are more electronegative than phosphorous, and phosphorous can never increase its oxidation state to more than $+5$, so how can it be a strong reducing agent?

[image: hypophosphorous_acid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you render the oxidation state of hypophosphorous as +5, then the electrons in the phosphorous-hydrogen bonds are attributed to the hydrogen atoms in those bonds.  You can do that, but then the hydrogen atoms involved have oxidation state -1 not +1.  So the reducing action of hypophosphorous acid is attributed to the negative oxidation state hydrogens.

Comment: so its all because of the negative partial charge on hydrogen that will be responsible for the reducing ability of the acid?

Comment: Hyrogen in a negative oxidation state (-1) is reducing.

Comment: can u plss explain how negative oxidation state of hydrogen is reducing?
 everytime i encountered with oxidation problems i always used to see the oxidation state of the central atom and then judge the oxidizing and reducing nature of the compound in a reaction..

Comment: The central atom is often decisive, but not always.  You really have to consider the oxidation state of all atoms.

Answer (score 1):

The oxidation state of phosphorus in H<sub>3</sub>PO<sub>4</sub> is indeed +5, but in this case you have only 2 and not 4 oxygens. This means that your P is only +1. The reason it's a reducing is because that P really wants to "become" +5.

Oscar Lanzi in his answer suggests that you can assume the H is H<sup>-</sup>, but this introduces a complication of this being a hydride, and these are not usually stable in solution. Note that this distinction is artificial. Eventually, this is all covalently bonded and the use oxidation numbers suggests ionic bonding.

Comment: _If_ you assume phosphorous is +5, then hydrogen attached to it is -1.  You can assume instead that all the H is +1 but must then accept P being +1.  No matter how you slice  it, you render something in a state that makes the molecule strongly reducing.

Comment: $\ce{H3PO2}$ not $\ce{H3PO4}$

Comment: @A.K. yea I know, that's what I said "only 2 and not 4 oxygens".